Error opening websocket client in R for AIS data
I'm trying to use websocket to connect to AIS data from AISstream.io but I keep getting a handle_read_frame error and I can't see anything in either the websocket documentation or the AISstream.io documentation that tells me why this may be the case. I make the connection, get a message, but the data from the message is not at all what I expect (a JSON formatted like one of the message models detailed in the API here. Instead I get 45 two digit hexadecimal numbers, then an error:
Message  7b 22 65 72 72 6f 72 22 3a 20 22 53 75 62 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 20 4f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 49 73 20 4d 61 6c 66 6f 72 6d 65 64 22 7d 
[2024-12-08 11:40:55] [error] handle_read_frame error: websocketpp.transport:7 (End of File)
 Close  1006 

Here's a MWE:
library(websocket)

{
  ws <- WebSocket$new("wss://stream.aisstream.io/v0/stream ")
  ws$onMessage(function(event) {
    d <- event$data
    cat(" Message ", d, "\n")
    })
  ws$onOpen(function(event) {
    ws$send("{\"APIKey\":\"<API_KEY>\", \"BoundingBoxes\":\"[[[-90, -180], [90, 180]]]\"}")
  })
  ws$onClose(function(event){
    c <- event$code
    cat(" Close ", c, "\n")
  })
}



Try without quoting the bounding box values.

translate the 'raw' vector to a character vector, like rawToChar(event$data), to see {\"error\": \"Subscription Object Is Malformed\"}
